# What other kinds of encoding support numpy besides of 3 specified inside (latin1, bytes , ASCII)

Tags: python, numpy, encoding

The function numpy.genfromtxt has a option to choose an specified encoding, looking inside npyio.py code it seems it supports those:
-latin1
-bytes
-ASCII

It says other encoding is not supported, so it means there are another kind of encoding, recently I found another one called: latin, is not exactly same as latin1 I believe, it seems to work when I read lines and extract information, but ... I wonder why it can support it even if it is not defined specifically. Is there another encoding am I missing and still works for numpy?.

Edit1: The numpy version is 1.20.1 in a python 3.8.8

Comment: `latin` is a supported  alias for `latin-1` - see the table in https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: I didnt think about aliases, now it makes sense why it doesn't show any warning, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part of `np.npyio` that explicitly checks for `-latin1 -bytes -ASCIC`
is

```
def load():
```

that is, the one that loads `np.save` files

```
encoding : str, optional
    What encoding to use when reading **Python 2 strings**. Only useful when
    loading Python 2 generated pickled files in Python 3, which includes
    npy/npz files containing object arrays. Values other than 'latin1',
    'ASCII', and 'bytes' are not allowed, as they can corrupt numerical
    data. Default: 'ASCII'
```

(my py2 emphasis)

For `genfromtxt`, the parameter is:

```
encoding : str, optional
    Encoding used to decode the inputfile. Does not apply when `fname` is
    a file object.  The special value 'bytes' enables backward compatibility
    workarounds that ensure that you receive byte arrays when possible
    and passes latin1 encoded strings to converters. Override this value to
    receive unicode arrays and pass strings as input to converters.  If set
    to None the system default is used. The default value is 'bytes'.
```

and the code only checks for `bytes`.  Otherwise it just passes the `encoding` parameter on to the file `open`.  So any encoding that the Python/OS file system handles is ok.

This `encoding` parameter is relatively new, and all I've used is `encoding=None`.